# Maximum product of coprime factors

Tags: algorithm, math

I essentially have a problem which boils down to the following: Given some (integer) number n, find a set of coprime numbers, say c = (c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, ..., c<sub>k</sub>), each less than n, which satisfy:

1) The product of all c<sub>i</sub> is maximal.

2) The sum of all c<sub>i</sub> is equal to n.

This may end up being a question for MathOverflow, but is there any kind of non-brute force algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your original problem?

Comment: @templatetypedef Calculating the element of largest order in the group of permutations S_{n}

Comment: look for math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're basically looking for the maximal least common multiple of any partition of n.  The product is known as Landau's function (see [OEIS A000793](https://oeis.org/A000793)).  This can be computed using dynamic programming, see [here](http://amca01.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/landaus-function/).